# Total sum using specific text and date

Tags: excel, windows, sumifs

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this as I have had a look everywhere online and can’t seem to get the correct answer.

I have a very large complicated excel sheet that contains products I have bought over several months.

What I am trying to achieve is to do a total sum using specific text within a time frame. I have managed to  achieve the total sum using specific 
Text by using this formula

=SUMIF(A2:A8,"*apple*",B2:B8)

But now what I want to do is add an extra string if possible to look between dates so that it looks for the sum apple of ‘apple’ within January.

Example of sheet

```
   A         B        C
product   price     date
apple     £150.00   Jan-16
apple     £150.00   Feb-16
pear      £100.00   Jan-16
pear      £100.00   Feb-16
apple     £150.00   Jan-16
banana    £200.00   Feb-16
banana    £200.00   Feb-16


Apple Total   
Jan       Feb       March
**£450.00**   

Pear Total    
Jan       Feb       March
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates look as if they are dates showing just month and day, so Jan-16 would be stored as 1-Jan-16. In this case you could use a SUMIFS like this

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$E1,$C$2:$C$8,DATEVALUE(E2&"-16"))
```

where the fruit to be matched is in E1 and the month in E2.

To match dates anywhere in the month, you could use EOMONTH

```
 =SUMIFS($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$E1,$C$2:$C$8,">="&DATEVALUE(E2&"-16"),$C$2:$C$8,"<="&EOMONTH(DATEVALUE(E2&"-16"),0))
```

Have changed first date in the screen shot below to illustrate the two formulae

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom, 

Many thanks for your answer. Im not sure this is doing exactly what i need it to do.

Maybe I didn't explain it correctly so apologies about that.

What I need the SUMIF to do is:

Example
Find all 'apple' from column A, Calculate the total (column B) but only for a certain time frame from column C.

So the SUMIF looks for apples, calculates the total spend for Jan-2016

Comment: There are two  'apple' rows in January, each with £150, so I was thinking that the result should be £300 ? And one apple in February which would be £150 ? The result in E3 is only £150 because I tried changing the first date to 10-jan-16 - the correct result for dates other than the 1st of the month is in I3.